# How do I recieve incoming mail on an email address in Linux

Tags: linux, email, email-server

Background:
My department does a lot of communication using email to ask and answer questions. We have an internal StackOverflow type board set up but it's a headache for them to log in to the VPN and post a question due to their circumstances.

What I am looking for:
I wanted a solution where they would ask a question like usual and add an extra mail recipient to their question (questions@company.com). The email would go to a Linux server and could possibly be fed to some program with a nice Web Interface for later viewing. Are there any solutions that do this? Any way that I can go about doing this. I'm relatively new to this type of thing so I really appreciate explanations.

Thanks

Comment: You will likely need an MTA server to process inbound and outbound mail. It's not as simple as a package install, due to intricacies of configuration.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I only need to recieve inbound mail. Are there any tutorials to do this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but specifically you'll want an SMTP server that receives mail from the outside world, and dispatches it to the database of the program you wish to use.

Comment: I use exim for this.  http://serverfault.com/questions/203721/email-to-a-web-application/203755#203755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots to do to set up an MTA.

- Pick one. Many to choose from. I've used `postfix` for years. `sendmail` is Allman's original MTA from way, way back.
- Install it and configure it to accept mail for a particular domain.
- test it by hand via `telnet` to make sure it's working. (Google "telnet smtp test" for MANY examples). You are pretending to be another MTA attempting to send mail.
- consider how you want to provide the last mile to your mail recipients. Unix is the original email platform; so literally your users can simply login to the server and read mail with `pine`, `elm`, `birch`, `emacs` etc. right off the file system (usually `/var/mail`). However, this day and age, it's crude and ugly. Consider running at least a `POP` server (POP has basically been deprecated since dial-up modems faded away). `IMAP` is the way to go; but that's a whole 'nother layer of sophistication you have to suss. My personal favorite is `cyrus imapd`. Whatever you choose, continue to test EXTENSIVELY.
- consider authentication. How many users? If you are dealing with a number smaller than 20, you can probably just do it by hand with the local 'nix password system. However, you will be the one and only arbiter in such a system. For larger setups, `LDAP` is probably the slickest way to go; but as with `IMAP` that is yet another whole service to grok, configure, test, and maintain. Nonetheless, you have to authenticate your users incoming to collect and send.
- consider spam filtering. This part is a major, big-league struggle. There are dozens of spam filtering tools. From grey-listing to SpamAssassin with many pieces in between. It is a war of attrition and you have to constantly upgrade and tweak your filters because the users are helpless.
- consider encryption. Allowing users to authenticate (see above) to your server either for sending via `smtp` or reading via `imap` in clear-text is criminal. It's bad enough they probably have weak passwords; broadcasting those passwords over your local ISP, telco carrier, et al. will only guarantee that your mail server becomes a spam-fountain.
- once you've got everything minty and tested, change your DNS such that you have new MX records pointing to your new server and try not to bite your nails too much.
- tail your mail log files endlessly.

This is NOT something to approach casually.

Comment: Hey ericx, I appreciate the very detailed explanation. So if I had an email address, let's say testemail@company.com and the password. I would have to do all this  to recieve email from others on the linux server?

Comment: No. If the mail is purely local to the server it's actually a lot easier. Assuming that no one is attempting to send mail from a mail program like `thunderbird` (i.e. everything is command-line) you don't actually have to run an MTA at all. The addresses become `testmail@servername.company.com` (not the more general `testmail@company.com`) and/or `testmail` (most server configs {this is configurable} will assume that an unspecified email address {i.e. no domain} is local delivery). The files in `/var/mail` or `/var/spool/mail` are `mbox`; so `mail`, `pine`, etc. will read it.

Comment: If you need some external source (StackExchange) to be able to send to these addresses, then you need both an MTA to accept in-coming smtp on port 25, and DNS MX listings for whomever@not-your-usual-domain-specifier SEPARATE from your regular company.com MX records.